# Remove line breaks excluding all before a group of numbers

Tags: notepad++, export-to-excel, line-breaks

I have a text file in which I need to remove line breaks, excluding the ones before a group of numbers.

For example, I would like to convert this:

```
237304||361234295694||360000316633||2021-05-12 18:51:26||Will it fit 123 model
Thanks T 
https://www.xxxxxxx.com 
238367||361234295694||360000316633||2021-05-17 13:38:12||I would like to return some items I bought.
```

Into this:

```
237304||361234295694||360000316633||2021-05-12 18:51:26||Will it fit 123 model Thanks T https://www.xxxxxxx.com 
238367||361234295694||360000316633||2021-05-17 13:38:12||I would like to return some items I bought.
```

To be clear, I need the first set of characters on each row to be these numbers you see here "237304" and "238367". They represent ticket numbers, and they are all unique.

I tried using "Join lines" but that removes all line breaks leaving me with one long text file with 1 line. How can I do this automated? The file is very large and it could take me days if I were to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d)`
- Replace with:    A space
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?!\d)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you!!!! this has already saved me a ton of work, I did notice there are still some line breaks left in between addresses like: 1400 test lane road, NA, 10020. Would it be possible to get around this?

Comment: @begaxo: Change `(?!\d)` into `(?!\d+\|\|)`